# How to upload file without clicking on the upload button( upload button not starting with <input> tag) using Selenium Webdriver.?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, bamboo

While running through bamboo(CI), my script is getting failed where all "upload file link" is not starting with the input tag. I am using Auto IT for uploading the file which is working fine locally and when I am trying to run through Bamboo on remote machine it is getting failed there.

So want to upload file from back-end where i don't want to click upload button.

Sendkeys() tried but not helpful in this scenario.

Thnaks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you try this.. is your webpage has browse button to locator file? if yes, pass the element to locatorUpload para and pass upload button element to locatorButton

```
public void UploadFile(By locatorUpload, By locatorButton, String filePath){

        driver.findElement(locatorUpload).sendKeys(filePath);
        waitForElementClickable(driver, locatorButton, 4);
        driver.findElement(locatorButton).click();

    }

public void waitForElementClickable(WebDriver driver, By locator, Integer timeoutInSeconds){
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, usually in this situation you need to do 3 steps:

- make input[type=file] element visible use javascript for that
- locate this input and use send_keys(PATH_TO_FILE_ON_YOUR_MACHINE)
- use javascript to trigger upload